# SQL: How to find the indexed date of the closest match from one column to the next?

Tags: sql, netezza

I have the following example MyTable that has been grouped by from an original data set.

I want to find the date in which the "plus_one" value is the closest match (first result above) to the "value" column in the given "dept". This needs to be produced in the "return_dt" column.

For example, in the first row, 1.2 in the "plus_one" column for the "Clothes" dept is closest to 1.36667 in the "value" column, so that first row needs to return the corresponding date (6/19/20) in the "return_dt" column for the same dept.

I'm familiar with window functions and using ORDER BY abs() to find the closest match. I'm having trouble putting them together to find the indexed date in a single table.

| end_dt | dept | value | plus_one | return_dt |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 6/30/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 0.2 | 1.2 | 6/19/2020 |
| 6/29/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/18/2020 |
| 6/28/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/18/2020 |
| 6/27/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/17/2020 |
| 6/26/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 0.573333 | 1.573333 | 6/17/2020 |
| 6/25/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 0.726667 | 1.726667 | 6/16/2020 |
| 6/24/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 0.853333 | 1.853333 | 6/15/2020 |
| 6/23/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.02 | 2.02 | 6/12/2020 |
| 6/22/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.166667 | 2.166667 | 6/12/2020 |
| 6/21/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.166667 | 2.166667 |  |
| 6/20/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.166667 | 2.166667 |  |
| 6/19/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.366667 | 2.366667 |  |
| 6/18/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.5 | 2.5 |  |
| 6/17/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.713333 | 2.713333 |  |
| 6/16/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.84 | 2.84 |  |
| 6/15/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/14/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/13/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/12/2020 0:00 | Clothes | 2.24 | 3.24 |  |
| … | … | … | … | … |
| 6/30/2020 0:00 | Toys | 0.2 | 1.2 | 6/19/2020 |
| 6/29/2020 0:00 | Toys | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/18/2020 |
| 6/28/2020 0:00 | Toys | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/18/2020 |
| 6/27/2020 0:00 | Toys | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/17/2020 |
| 6/26/2020 0:00 | Toys | 0.573333 | 1.573333 | 6/17/2020 |
| 6/25/2020 0:00 | Toys | 0.726667 | 1.726667 | 6/16/2020 |
| 6/24/2020 0:00 | Toys | 0.853333 | 1.853333 | 6/15/2020 |
| 6/23/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.02 | 2.02 | 6/12/2020 |
| 6/22/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.166667 | 2.166667 | 6/12/2020 |
| 6/21/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.166667 | 2.166667 |  |
| 6/20/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.166667 | 2.166667 |  |
| 6/19/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.366667 | 2.366667 |  |
| 6/18/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.5 | 2.5 |  |
| 6/17/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.713333 | 2.713333 |  |
| 6/16/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.84 | 2.84 |  |
| 6/15/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/14/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/13/2020 0:00 | Toys | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/12/2020 0:00 | Toys | 2.24 | 3.24 |  |
| … | … | … | … | … |
| 6/30/2020 0:00 | Games | 0.2 | 1.2 | 6/19/2020 |
| 6/29/2020 0:00 | Games | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/18/2020 |
| 6/28/2020 0:00 | Games | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/18/2020 |
| 6/27/2020 0:00 | Games | 0.393333 | 1.393333 | 6/17/2020 |
| 6/26/2020 0:00 | Games | 0.573333 | 1.573333 | 6/17/2020 |
| 6/25/2020 0:00 | Games | 0.726667 | 1.726667 | 6/16/2020 |
| 6/24/2020 0:00 | Games | 0.853333 | 1.853333 | 6/15/2020 |
| 6/23/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.02 | 2.02 | 6/12/2020 |
| 6/22/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.166667 | 2.166667 | 6/12/2020 |
| 6/21/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.166667 | 2.166667 |  |
| 6/20/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.166667 | 2.166667 |  |
| 6/19/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.366667 | 2.366667 |  |
| 6/18/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.5 | 2.5 |  |
| 6/17/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.713333 | 2.713333 |  |
| 6/16/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.84 | 2.84 |  |
| 6/15/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/14/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/13/2020 0:00 | Games | 1.986667 | 2.986667 |  |
| 6/12/2020 0:00 | Games | 2.24 | 3.24 |  |
| … | … | … | … | … |

I've tried a correlated query like

```
select t.*,
      (select t2.end_dt
       from t t2
       where t2.value > t.plus_one
       order by t2.value
       limit 1
      ) as return_dt
from t;
```

but Netezza says "ERROR [HY000] ERROR:  (2) This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting"

Any ideas how I can create the column for the return_dt?

Comment: Don't forget, you can join a table to itself

Comment: @Cosmos . . . Netezza is not Postgres, so I removed the Postgres tag.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks, I'm still learning :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lateral join or correlated subquery seems like this simplest approach:

```
select t.*,
       (select t2.end_dt
        from t t2
        where t2.dept = t.dept and
              t2.value > t.plus_one
        order by t2.value
        limit 1
       ) as return_dt
from t;
```

This is rather painful (and inefficient) to write without a correlated subquery.  But . . .

```
select t.*
from (select t.end_dt, t.dept, t.value, t.plus_one,
             tnext.end_dt as return_dt,
             row_number() over (partition by t.end_dt, t.dept, t.value, t.plus_one order by tnext.value asc) as seqnum
      from t left join
           t tnext
           on tnext.dept = t.dept and
              tnext.value > t.plus_one
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks, this looks about where I need to be. However it seems like this solution doesn't work with my full data set which is actually grouped by a separate field. I get the following error from Netezza "ERROR [HY000] This form of correlated query is not supported - consider rewriting"

I've made edits to the above question to a include a fuller representation of the situation, any chance you could help me modify?

Comment: @Cosmos . . . Does it help if there is an equality condition on the `dept`?

Comment: Incredible, this works flawlessly. Thank you so much!!!